# How can i count user sessions grouped by users with linux bash command?

Tags: linux, bash, session

How can i count user sessions grouped by users with Linux bash command?

i have an application that runs on a Linux OS. To use the application users start up a terminal and log in using their Linux account then they are prompted with the application log in menu to which they enter they application login credentials.

my problem is that when the users finish using the app and log out their Linux sessions remain active. so every now and then i have to run the command

```
killall -u [Linux username]
```

for users with more then 3 active sessions.

i used the command

```
w | sort
```

to get a list of users but then i couldn't find any help online showing how to group the list according to Linux usernames.

i intend to group the output list according to users names and then count the usernames with more then 3 lines and then run the

```
killall -u [username]
```

i think many people may find it useful to know how many sessions a particular username (`userid`) has active because these may slow the overall performance of the machine. in my case the machine hosting the app has a deteriorating response time every time the active sessions build up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
w | sed '1,2d' | cut -f1 -d' ' | sort | uniq -c
```

This will return one line per user which contains the # of sessions per user.  For example:

```
       1 root
      15 sa
       2 superuser
       1 user1
       3 user2
```

In this case, the user `sa` has 15 sessions, and `user2` has 3 sessions.

Comment: @DannyDaglas. The script was perfect, thank you. I can now continue to the next stage.